# Add custom audible feedback to Android button

Tags: android, onclick, ringtone

I want to add custom audible feedback to a button press (various click sounds encoded as *.ogg) I've done this by using the RingtoneManager to create Ringtones for each of the clicks and then .play() them in the onClick() method. This works but seems a little sluggish. This leaves me wondering if there is a better way to attach a custom sound effect to a button press. I've scanned the Button reference page and all I found was playSoundEffect() which seems to handle only system defined sounds.

thanks,
hank

Comment: For short audio clips (few seconds) use SoundPool. Here is nice tutorial with simple example: (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html) Basically you create SoundPool, load data and play it. Hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SoundPool-  they work it preloads the data into memory (so no file reads which cause sluggishness).  Ringtones are definitely not what you want to be using here-  those are typically much longer and not time critical (delaying a ringtone by a second or so isn't a problem, whereas delaying a button sound effect by that long is).